# What's the entry point of GUI program in linux?

Tags: linux, user-interface

In windows it's `WinMain`,

what's it in linux?

Or is it still `main`?

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: This depends on the library....and which linux build/distro you're using.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows PE (Portable Executable) format has a flag in the header that states whether the executable is *console* or *windowed*. Depending on which it is, Windows will allocate a console window for the application, or not. This also determines whether the entry point is `main` or `WinMain`.

The Linux ELF format does not have a similar flag. The entry point is always `main`. The concept of "console window" is entirely different in Linux.

(Note that the above simplifies the issue somewhat, since the entry point you're talking about is where the *user* code starts. The compiler/linker always supplies some runtime library startup code that runs before your user entry point is called, which is where the real entry point is.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the GUI library that you're using. The entry point for a C *program* (in hosted mode) is always *main* (usually, it's in the C startup code which configures things and then calls main which is where *your* code starts.

Some environments provide their own version of `main` to set things up before calling your code. However, [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29#Qt_hello_world) and [KDE](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/First_program) (as two examples) still uses `main` and you're required to set the envirnment up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is always main().

Linux, per se, does not distinguish between GUI and non-GUI programs. It doesn't have a flag in the executable to say "this is a console app" or "this is a window app".

Strictly speaking, the entry point is NOT main(), but _start or something. However, if you're linking with the standard C library or some variant of it, it tends to be main() by convention in the C language.